# How can a range be different from its specs?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here is my code.

```
    LibStart = 8942
    LibEnd = 9092
    With SecRng.Document
        Set LibRng = .Range(LibStart, LibEnd)

        Debug.Print Left(LibRng.Text, 50)
        Debug.Print .Range(LibStart, LibStart + 50).Text
    End With
```

I expect the two printouts to be identical but they aren't. Why?

The first print is as expected. When I select the corresponding text in the document `? Selection.Start` will give me 9042.

The second printout starts exactly one paragraph below the expected. When I select the text in the document `? Selection.Start` will return 9062. `? Selection.Characters.Count` of the first paragraph = 20. It all adds up but why? Where is the fault in my reasoning?

There are some double-byte characters in the range. LibEnd = 9092 may not be what I will agree to. But I think it's immaterial to the immediate problem, at least, because there are no double-byte characters within the first 50 I'm printing out, one way or the other, and when I select the entire range by name the correct range gets selected. I think that's a dead end.

The reason must be, I thought, in a difference between `Document.Range` and `SecRng.Document.Range`. So I added a few characters to the 20. The output didn't change: The second print starts at the second paragraph, same as before but 25 characters later instead of the previous 20. Therefore, apparently, it's not a count of characters but a count of paragraphs.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is "SecRng" ? A Range's (and the Selection's) .TextRetrievalMode settings may have a bearing on this, certainly if you have any field codes in your text (see, e.g.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62040233/get-full-range-text-to-string/62089119). .

Comment: `SecRng` is a range comprising one section in the document (the last one in this case). Often miracles such as I encounter are due to faulty test procedures. Overnight I thought of ways my tests could be misleading and will implement some ideas during the day. Please watch this space.